# How to Use the "Source" Parameter with the REST API Of Twitter?

Tags: javascript, firefox, rest, twitter

my name is Fernando and I want to write an extension for Firefox which is a client for Twitter.Eu been studying and came across the fact of having to use OAuth to bring up the "From Name" as example. Fact is that I've never seen it before, I am not very mainstreamed with OAuth and Firefox does not provide facilities to use it fully and applications known as EchoFon TweetDeck and never appeared to use OAuth, and simplicity is something I take much to facilitate the work on user to it, I want to use REST, setting the field 'Source' some Forma.How I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't unless you're using OAuth.

It was possible in the past to ask Twitter to register custom source names for clients that are using Basic Auth. Short after introducing OAuth, Twitter stopped accepting new application for custom source names, unless they use OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Twitter's official FAQ post on this here: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/FAQ#HowdoIget“fromMyApp”appendedtoupdatessentfrommyAPIapplication